# Updating copied object also updates the parent object

Tags: javascript

I have got an object of defaults, then some values which will over-ride the defaults. However when i use `Object.assign` to create a new object, and update this, the defaults also get changed.

```js
let defaults = { test: 'hello world' };
let values = { test: 'beep' };
let merged = Object.assign(defaults, values);

merged.test = 'updated'

// defaults: { test: 'updated' }
```

Defaults should remain the same and only `merged` should get updated. I was under the impression that `Object.assign` copies the object, not references it.

Comment: Use spread operator to merge ``let merged = {...defaults, ...values}``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in following way.

```js
let defaults = { test: 'hello world' };
let values = { test: 'beep' };
let merged = Object.assign({}, defaults, values);

merged.test = 'updated';

console.log(defaults)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try: `let merged = Object.assign({}, defaults, values);`

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try to clone deppe your `merged` array. Here working example using `lodash`:

```js
let defaults = { test: 'hello world' };
let values = { test: 'beep' };
let merged = Object.assign(defaults, values);
let merged_deepclone = _.cloneDeep(merged);

merged_deepclone.test = 'updated';

console.log(defaults);
console.log(merged_deepclone);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```